# Asymptotic formula for almost primes

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, asymptotics

I have developed a formula for almost primes which is far more accurate asymptotically than Landau's well known

$$\pi_k(n) \sim \left( \frac{n}{\log n} \right) \frac{(\log\log n)^{k-1}}{(k - 1)!}$$

(Landau's is not good for high $n$, whereas the one I have been working on actually gets more accurate the higher $n$ becomes - see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/35927/asymptotic-density-of-k-almost-primes).)

Is this of any significance?

Just out of interest, I have included some plots up to $n=9$:

[image]

where actual is green, Landau is blue, & mine is red.

*(Note: I have changed the scale in each one.)*

Comment: I cannot understand what means  "plots up to n=9" ? The first plot (n=1) is obvious prime counting function,  i.e. k=1 and so on up to k=9 ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this is of significance. Why don't you write a paper and submit it to a journal?

Comment: I have never written a paper before. How would I go about submitting it to a journal? I have no proof for it either, but have tested it fairly exhaustively. Does this matter?

Comment: @martin yes, it does matter (since it means that your formula might not be more accurate for very large $n.$) I would writing up your ideas, and talking to a number theorist. You have to write things very carefully (include the results of your experiments), lest they take you for a crank. If they think you are serious, they will be happy to talk.

Comment: Can you tell me where I might go about finding a number theorist who might look at the work?

Comment: @martin. I totally agree with what Igor Rivin told. This is worth to be published even if you do not have the complete proof.

Comment: @martin. Where are you currently ?

Comment: I am based in the UK

Comment: I would say, write it your thoughts first (carefully). You can email them to me, and I can tell you what I think and whether/where to send it on.

Comment: Great, thank you! I will take some time to write it up properly. Again, many thanks.

Comment: @martin. Same for me ! My e-mail address is in my profile.

Comment: OK - many thanks!

Comment: What happened with this? Was a paper published? I'm interested in OP's function...