# Reference request for proof of Landau's generalised PNT

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, prime-numbers

Could someone please point me in the direction of a proof for Landau's asymptotic formula for k-almost primes:

$$\pi_k(n) \sim \left( \frac{n}{\log n} \right) \frac{(\log\log n)^{k-1}}{(k - 1)!}$$

I realise that it was derived directly from the PNT - would like to see the steps involved though.

Comment: I'm not sure, but it might be in Davenport's Multiplicative Number Theory.

Comment: @martin: ALso, have you checked the reference here? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_prime, that is: ^ Tenenbaum, Gerald (1995). Introduction to Analytic and Probabilistic Number Theory. Cambridge University Press. ISBN 0-521-41261-7.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions - can't seem to find it in Davenport though - do you have a chapter ref?

Comment: See also the discussion at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/35927/asymptotic-density-of-k-almost-primes

Comment: I note that just a couple of weeks ago, you claimed to have a better formula than Landau's; http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/607895/asymptotic-formula-for-almost-primes

Comment: Yes, I am working on a proof, but only a partial proof may be possible :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original source, as far as I know, is Landau's *Handbuch der Lehre von der Verteilung der Primzahlen*. An approachable modern version (in English!) is

Gerald Tenenbaum, Introduction to Analytic and Probabilistic Number Theory. Cambridge University Press (1995).

Comment: Thanks - yes, English is preferable!

Comment: Try as I might, I can't find a proof of it. At the start of chapter II.6, Tenenbaum says that"It is easy to show that ....", but I can't find where he shows it!

Comment: @martin: I'm pretty sure I read Tenenbaum's proof of the theorem, so either you're missing it or it's in another of his works. I'll see if I can find anything, though my uni library is snowed out at the moment (!).

Comment: Great, thanks - much appreciated! :)