# Submission of papers to ArXiv or similar

Tags: soft-question

Apologies for posting such a similar question in a relatively short space of time, but I have a paper that I would like to submit to arXiv.org, whilst it is in the process of being reviewed (which I realise can take a very long time).

However, the submission guidelines say that it must be endorsed by someone currently affiliated with ArXiv. I have heard that it is possible to publish on  vixra.org, but that it is not really advisable. Is there a viable alternative? Or is there a way to contact someone who might be interested in endorsing publication on ArXiv?

Also, I don't know whether it is common practice (or even permitted) to submit to multiple journals.

Comment: 1.  It is not common practice to submit to multiple journals at the same time.  Most journals specifically disallow this.

Comment: 2.  Look on Arxiv for people who have published similar stuff, and ask them to endorse your paper.

Comment: Great - thanks - that is good to know!

Comment: I would have a look, but am a little worried that if I don't know the person, whether it would be a good idea to send my paper to them?

Comment: Are you worried they might steal your results?  Actually, it is a fair concern if you don't know the person, and that kind of stuff does happen.  Not much, but it can.

Comment: Yes, a little :/

Comment: Do you think you have solved some major problem?  Or is it some interesting but minor result that only specialists will be interested in?

Comment: If it is solving a major problem, there is a good chance you are wrong.  If you are right, then the community will ferret out the weasel who steals it.  Especially if you email more than one person asking for an endorsement.

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/607895/asymptotic-formula-for-almost-primes). I don't really know how important it is.

Comment: If it is a minor result, then there is a good chance no-one will steal it.  Again, emailing several different people, and sending it to all of them in one email, so that they can see you copied it to several other people, will minimize the risk.

Comment: One more thing.  Send it as PDF.  It looks bad if they don't have the original TeX.

Comment: Ok -thanks for the advice. I would really like to see if I could perhaps speak to an academic face to face first. Still no clue as to who to send it to though!

Comment: In that case, you have already "published" the result in some sense, so it is unlikely people will steal it.  You could ask on stackexchange if anyone here is willing to endorse it.

Comment: Would you suggest I ask it as a new question?

Comment: - I presume you mean MathStackExchange?

Comment: Try Igor Rivin first.  As for "new question?", I don't know.

Comment: It seems to me that you'd be more likely to find endorsers on MathOverflow, since that's the site specifically dedicated to research mathematics. I don't know, though, whether they consider such a question on topic.

Comment: Many thanks for everbody's suggestions :)

Comment: viXra.org become terrible, they even allow papers who contain only a title and nothing else.

Comment: @martin, did you ever get the paper on the arXiv (or elsewhere)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't submit to multiple journals; they explicitly forbid it.  Pick the best one for your paper and wait for the decision; if you're rejected, then you can pick another.

If you are in any way affiliated with a university, you can certainly request that a professor there endorse you.  How did you come to do the research in the paper?  If you worked entirely on your own, it nonetheless benefits you to send a copy to a few people of repute who can comment on it; in fact, an important part of establishing the trust of the community (with respect to the validity and importance of your results) is having a few names in the acknowledgments that demonstrate that you've gotten at least some people interested.  You can ask one of those people for an endorsement.

Comment: Ok, I'll do that. Apparently the average time is 4 months though! - Noo, I am not affiliated with any university - I just have a (an over?!) healthy interest in the subject! Unfortunately, I do not know of anyone in the field, and am a little wary of 'cold calling'!

Comment: Four months is nothing: when I published my thesis, it took thirteen months to get a report back.  Life doesn't stop while the journal's wheels turn, though. As for cold calling, just state your situation clearly and modestly and explain why you choose the person in question to ask. People are often generous.